# Does $\,x>0\,$ hint that $\,x\in\mathbb R\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

> Does $x>0$ suggest that $x\in\mathbb R$?

For numbers not in $\,\mathbb R\,$ (e.g. in $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$), their sizes can't be compared.

So can I omit "$\,x\in\mathbb R\,$" and just write $\,x>0\,$?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure similar binary relations $\cdot>\cdot$ are defined on $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, too. How are you going to distinguish which might be meant?

Comment: Well, it is in $N$ and $Z$ it is also in $R$.

Comment: @nayrb Umm, 2.5 is in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{N}$ nor $\mathbb{Z}$. Yet $2.5 > 0$. So the point still stands, out of context it could mean  either a positive integer or a position real (or a positive rational, or a positive.. anything in any ordered field)

Comment: Yes, of course. My point is that if x>0 it must be real. It may also be an integer, but integers are also real.

Comment: One could also write $\omega>0$, and $\omega\notin\mathbb{R}$ since it is the first infinite ordinal.

Comment: @nayrb But in that case it amounts to saying "let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be an integer", which is horribly redundant. It doesn't add any information, it's just confusing.

Comment: Authors of complex analysis textbooks do often take this shortcut (e.g. Eli Stein and Rami Shakarchi), and within complex analysis I feel this is fine. Within this subject, there should be no confusion, especially once readers know that $\mathbb{C}$ is not an ordered field.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It really depends on context. But be safe; just say $x > 0, x\in \mathbb R$.

Omitting the clarification can lead to misunderstanding it. Including the clarification takes up less than a centimeter of space. Benefits of clarifying the domain greatly outweigh the consequences of omitting the clarification.

Besides one might want to know about rationals greater than $0$, or integers greater than $0$, and we would like to use $x \gt 0$ in those contexts, as well.

ADDED NOTE: That *doesn't mean* that *after* having clarified the context, and/or defined the domain, you should *still* use the qualification "$x\in \mathbb R$" **every time** you subsequently write $x \gt 0$, in a proof, for example. But if there's any question in your mind about whether or not to include it, error on the side of inclusion.

Comment: Deserves another thumbs up! +1

Comment: It looks like 1.5cm to me...

Comment: @ZhenLin You might be right: I read the question/typed my answer on my iPod ;-)

Comment: The clarification takes up some number (1 or 1.5 seems large) of square centimeters unless you are measuring the inline space in your font.  But the point is good.  +1

Answer (score 19):

One might be able to decode that notation, but why force this puzzle on the reader?

Answer (score 8):

Easiest solution is to just say
$$
x\in\mathbb{R}^+
$$
Expresses both conditions in one hit.

Comment: From my experience, more often than not, $0\in {\bf R}^+$. ${\bf R}_{>0}$ is less amibguous.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^+$ means *positive* reals, hence the symbol. Zero isn't positive. Note that $0\ni\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Well, the fact that the same symbol means different things to different people seems like a clear indication that it should be avoided.

Comment: Oops - I just realised that I used $\ni$ when I meant it to be $\not\in$. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GlenO: I just said that in practice, ${\bf R}^+$ (or, more often, ${\bf R}_+$) often denotes *nonnegative* reals. It's commonplace, for instance, when discussing manifolds with boundary.

Comment: @GlenO [this query](http://latexsearch.com/latexFacets.do?searchInput={\mathbb%20R}^%2B&stype=exact) shows that even in differential equations (where the notation seems most prevalent), both conventions are used.

Comment: @tomasz: perhaps this is a regional thing. I was taught that, for instance, if you wanted to say non-negative integers, it would be $\mathbb{Z}^{\text{nonneg}}$ (or variants thereof), and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ meant positive integers... and the same in the case of reals, rationals, etc.

Comment: Well, while I have encountered ${\bf R}^+$ in both meanings, I have yet to encounter anything like ${\bf Z}^{\textrm{nonneg}}$ or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 4):

There are ordered fields which strictly extend the real numbers, there $x>0$ is meaningful, but need not imply $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Not just ordered fields by any means. To go in one direction, $0$ could be taken to be the *ordinal* $0$, and it could also be the *cardinal* $0$ (which may or may not be the same thing, depending on the definitions in play, but these are generally *not* considered real numbers). In an overlapping context, $0$ could be the bottom element of an ordered set/class. In a different context, it could be the zero of an ordered ring. Altogether, assuming that $0 \in \mathbb R$ is just not a good plan.

Comment: BTW, I know that Asaf Karagila is perfectly aware of this; my comment was for the benefit of the asker.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, everything depends on context. I usually prefer to say things like

> For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$, ...

instead of

> For any $x>0$, ...

to remove ambiguity, but I'm not insistent on it; I might be willing to sacrifice the "$x\in\mathbb{R}$" if it's making an [orphan at the end of a paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans), for example.

In contrast, everyone knows what

> For any $\epsilon>0$, ...

almost always means, and it doesn't really add anything to say $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$. Of course, if you want to write $\epsilon>0$ and $\epsilon$ is **not** an element of $\mathbb{R}$, then it is all the more incumbent upon you to warn the reader of this non-standard use.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite would be "$x$ is a positive real number". Simple, clear, unambiguous, and no strange symbols to decipher.

It's a bit long, maybe, but who cares -- the point of writing is clarity, not brevity.

Comment: Well, no, it's still ambiguous. You've said $x$ **is** a positive real number. But **will** it remain one in the future? See it's those edge cases you gotta look out for... :p

Comment: @Thomas So it depends on what the meaning of the word "is" is? :-)

Comment: In my view "$x$ is a positive real number" means exactly the same as "$x \in \mathbb R$ and $x > 0$". I either case, we omit the part that says "and will always remain so". I would think that this is implied and understood. But, anyway, I'm willing to withdraw my claim of "unambiguous" and replace it with "no less ambiguous than the other symbol-laden versions".

Comment: And, if you're not careful, the fretting about the edge cases can easily overwhelm and obscure the central argument. Actually, this is true both in mathematics and programming. The edge cases do need to be handled, but they should be on the edges of the discussion. I like Donald Knuth's idea of "telling lies" (ignoring the edge cases, at least temporarily).

Comment: @bubba It was a joke. You are of course right that it is implied and that too much symbolism can often make things worse when a simple english sentence is perfectly adequate.

Comment: @Thomas -- Oh. OK. Got it. Well, actually, now that I know it's a joke, I think it's a pretty good one. This site has quite a lot of suggestions that (in my view) are laughable, and I find it increasingly difficult to decide which ones are actually jokes.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to say something like "there is a real number $x > 0$ such that...," or "let $x > 0$ be a real number," *etc.* depending on what you want to say about $x$.  This avoids ambiguity, and also using words to describe the new symbol being introduced makes life easier for the reader.  The goal of writing (even mathematical writing) should not be to avoid redundancy.